# PGP encryption is not working with error gpg: Note: '--decrypt' is not considered an option

Tags: command

I am trying to run below command in CMD and getting below error
echo NTDIND-@11$7at3-1234| gpg.exe --batch --yes --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-fd 0 -o C:/Users/INT0IIAdmin/Documents/Mid server/agent/export/Allstate/Incoming/Import.csv --decrypt C:/Users/INT0IIAdmin/Documents/Mid server/agent/export/Allstate/Incoming/Import.pgp

**error**
gpg: Note: '--decrypt' is not considered an option
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
usage: gpg [options] [filename]

If i change the file path as below if i keep it in desktop it is working as expected

**working command**
echo NTDIND-@11$7at3-1234| gpg.exe --batch --yes --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-fd 0 -o C:/Users/INT0IIAdmin/Documents/Import.csv --decrypt C:/Users/INT0IIAdmin/Documents/Import.pgp

What could be the issue please help here.

Comment: How is this a C# question? It doesn't sound like a *programming* question at all, but instead "How should I use gpg?" If you believe this *is* a programming question, please clarify it.

Comment: `C:/Users/INT0IIAdmin/Documents/Mid server/agent/export/Allstate/Incoming/Import.pgp` has a space in it, it therefore needs to be quoted.